# Visual Studio Just In Time Debugger Returns Exit Code 0

Tags: vsjitdebugger

I am writing negative tests for my CI and I have one which aborts the process by dereferencing a null pointer. Now for this situation I expect an exit code of -1073741819 but when I have JIT debugger running it ends up returning an exit code of 0.

If there a way to get JIT to pass through the actually code that occured when the process terminated or does it always default to returning 0?

Comment: Can you provide code of your test?

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to. It is for work and is considered confidential.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior is real. I have seen it when launching the Visual Studio JIT debugger on process start via a registry key entry for a particular executable. The return code of the program always zero. I did not try detaching the debugger before program exit. Maybe that would help?